# Google App Engine - Early Look at Java Language Support tutorial

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Recently I have started playing with google app engine and eclipse trying to create a simple  java app. The problem is that the "guestbook" example given today in the official GAE website is is slightly different, more complicated and I struggle to remake the example on this video which you most probably already have seen:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3GT4-m_6RQ

If anyone have seen this code on some other website or know any other resources such as books, journals, articles, etc. that will help me to recreate the example on my own, this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best for any beginner.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/